# Getting error response from backend Flask in ajax code even if the if statement is returning true value

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to get the value of a if statement in flask backend and sending a ajax response to the front end. 
Even if the if-statement in the back end is true but still in the ajax front end its showing error response

i am trying to compare the two variables, if true it resdirects to google else it sends a error response in the form of ajax

```js
function myFunction() {

$.ajax({
        url: '/ValidateOTP',
        type: 'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify( $('#OTP').val()),
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(response){

        },
        error: function(error){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
};


<!-- language: python -->

@app.route('/ValidateOTP', methods=['GET','POST'])
def ValidateOTP():
    OTP = request.get_json()
    if OTP==otpnow:
        return render_template('https://www.google.co.in')
    else:
        return json.dumps({'status': 'failure', })
```

Comment: You could print values of `OTP` and `otpnow` to see why they are different. What is the value of `otpnow`? Is `OTP` just a text or some JSON-ish data structure? If it's just a text, then you don't need to encode/decode JSON and could send it as it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I have checked the OTP and otpnow at that point of time..they are same. but, i dont have any clue why the ajax getting negative response

Comment: For your Information....otpnow is the value of global variable which i am getting from another method(which generates the OTP and sends the mail to the user)

Comment: render_template needs a template path, so `'https://www.google.co.in'` is probably causing exception. Do you see it in the Flask log?

Comment: i have created a html page and inserted that html page name in render_template...but still getting this exception...                                        raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: login.html

Comment: Check the flask docs. Templates are located in `templates` folder.